# How do I build a Tableau divide function based on a case statement?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

In Tableau I have a fully normalized dataset e.g. I have a field for a dimension (country) a field for metric (profit and sales) and a field for value (fact numbers).

I was wondering if I can write a case statement where I divide profit by sales e.g. in SQL it would be something similar to:

```
(case when metric = 'profit' then [value] else 0 ) / (case when metric = 'sales' then [value])
```

I've tried building the case statement using the Tableau calculated field functionality but it returns zero - I suspect because I'm trying to do this in 1 step whilst in SQL I think it might be a 2 step process.

Please note that the simple solution of re-structuring the data isn't really an option as this creates other issues (not outlined in my simplistic example).

Answer (score 1):

Try  this:

step 1: calculated field `Profit`:

if metric='Profit' then value end

step 2: calculated field `sales`:

if metric='sales' then value end

step 3 : one calculated field to divide `Profit/sales`

then you use this to get the result.

Comment: So this logic makes sense and I can run through the process in Tableau.  The numbers coming back aren't correct though.  I'll need to look into this in more detail.  One thing I notice is that when I pull the step 3 metric into the pane it gives me an AGG(step3) rather than the SUM(step3).  Not sure if this has something to do with it.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want a row level calculation "profit / sales" ratio for each individual transaction, or whether you want an aggregate calculation grouped by the dimensions in your visualization. The second case equates to "sum(profit) / sum(sales) group by ...". In that case, Tableau displays AGG() around your calculated field name to indicate that the aggregation function is built into the calculation instead of selectable separately on the shelf. If this doesn't sound familiar, brush up on how SQL GROUP BY works.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your dataset has `profit` and `sales` in different rows .Which might have been giving the trouble. The good news is that with Tableau 9.0 and later this can be achieved easily using LOD Calculations .

So you can try creating a calculated field as

```
country_profit : {FIXED country : SUM(CASE WHEN metric = 'PROFIT' then value)}
country_sales : {FIXED country : SUM(CASE WHEN metric = 'Sales' then value)}
result : country_profit / country_sales
```

Let us know if this works .